# Difference between mod_rewrite redirects?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following two mod_rewrite redirects. They both appear to do the same thing, but I'm not sure why one is two lines longer than the other. (I've been using the longer one btw):

## 1:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^$ shows [L]
```

## 2:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /shows [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra two lines simply forward requests for any page at `example.com` to the same page at `www.example.com`, performing a 301 permanent redirect (hence the `R=301...`).

It's good practice not to have duplicate content on two domains (for SEO purposes) so most people these days forward `example.com` to `www.example.com`; the other way around is also perfectly valid and quite widely used (ie. redirecting `www.example.com` to `example.com`).

Comment: Ahh that makes sense. Much appreciated. Now only if I could find a way to have the URL be only the base domain after the redirect, instead of having the subdirectory `shows/` at the end of it. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, can you give an example with two URLs: one that you want to rewrite from and one you want to rewrite to?

Comment: Well the redirect is working fine. A browser pointed towards `http://www.example.com/` is redirected to `http://www.example.com/shows/`. But I'm wondering how to have the browser still show only `http://www.example.com/` after the redirect. Is that possible?

Comment: With the rule you've got the URL shouldn't change in the browser, that would only normally happen if you were performing a redirect

Comment: See that's what I thought as well, but it *is* changing... every time! Any ideas why? That was the reason I was using mod_write in the first place, instead of just a redirect. Sigh.

Comment: I don't I'm afraid, I've seen it asked on SO before though so try searching the site...if you don't find anything just post a new question with that problem someone's bound to give you a good answer

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the advice you did give. Hope I can figure out what I'm doing wrong.